# Weblogic T3 connection from C# does not work on remote server

Tags: c#, queue, weblogic, t3

I am trying to connect to a Weblogic server, using T3 protocol, in order to read and write from specific Weblogic queues.

I have built a solution that does this and works correctly on a local installation of Weblogic, but context creation fails when trying to connect to a remote Weblogic server.

```
            var paramMap = new Dictionary<string, Object>
            {
                [Constants.Context.PROVIDER_URL] = "t3://" + host + ":" + port,
                [Constants.Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL] = "weblogic",
                [Constants.Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS] = "welcome1."
            };
            var context = ContextFactory.CreateContext(paramMap);
```

The error returned is:

```
WebLogic.Messaging.MessageException: 'Problem creating context 
 --> System.Exception: Expect hello response but got 6,0
   at WebLogic.Messaging.Transport.T3Client.T3Connection.ProcessHelloResponse(Stream input)
   at WebLogic.Messaging.Transport.T3Client.T3Connection..ctor(String hostAddress, Int32 port, Int32 soketTO, T3PeerInfo peerInfo, SByte serviceId)
   at WebLogic.Messaging.Transport.T3Client.TransportSPIImpl.StartClient(String host, Int32 port, TransportUserCfgParameters paras, IMarshalReadableFactory mrf, ITransportThreadPool pool)
   at WebLogic.Messaging.Physical.T3TransportFactory.CreateT3Transport(String host, Int32 port, TransportUserCfgParameters paras)
   at WebLogic.Messaging.Physical.T3TransportFactory.CreateT3Transport(IDictionary`2 paramMap)'
```

Things of note:

I am using the WebLogic.Messaging nuget package, version 1.3.4

https://www.nuget.org/packages/WebLogic.Messaging/1.3.4?_src=template

.NET Framework 4.7.2

Remote Weblogic server version: 12.2.1.4.0

Localhost weblogic server version: 14.1.1.0.0

I've checked all available documentation and as far as I can tell the weblogicMessaging.dll should be compatible with both versions.

I honestly don't know what else to try, I've checked Weblogic settings on both machines and they are identical, one works, the other does not. Could it be a networking issue?

Comment: From Oracle support, this issue can raise if Dynatrace Agent is runing in your remote WebLogic server instance. Is that the case ?

Comment: Have you tried this?
https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Middleware/2499797_1.html#FIX

Comment: @EmmanuelCollin indeed, we have dynatrace agent running there. we have since turned it off and connections do work, however, on production we can't turn it off. still looking for a fix with dynatrace up and running

Comment: @gliesefire i cannot access that link, my oracle account does not have the needed subscription. please post the solution in this thread

Comment: The link from Oracle support will give you the same information : disable Dynatrace in your prod env. 
That's the answer from Oracle. I understand from your point of view this solution is not acceptable. May be you can contact Dynatrace support team and explain your issue.